# How to read Weblogic JMS Queue message count in Java

Tags: java, jms, weblogic12c

We need to monitor JMS Queue/Topic in Java and what would be the respective weblogic jar which supports monitoring.

Comment: Which version of WebLogic Server are you using ?

Comment: We are using WebLogic Server 12C

Comment: Start reading this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/JMXCU/toc.htm), chapter 4 will give you code samples.